# Tomasulo's algorithm + MIPS 5 stages pipeline + branch prediction

Tags: algorithm, cpu-architecture

I'm learning about Tomasulo's algorithm and I think I understand it. What I can't figure out is how it is integrated with the MIPS 5 stage pipeline that is discussed in Hennessy and Patterson? Also how would one integrate branch prediction with Tomasulo? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad for stackoverflow, but you might find this 2 hour long video useful if you have enough background in computer architecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMrotwfPWCc

Answer (score 1):

Tomasulo's keeps track of dynamic scheduling of instructions which comes in play when after decode you have multiple ports to execute different instructions as well as hardware resources for the instructions to wait, schedule, forward result. MIPS 5 stage in-order pipeline can not issue/dispatch multiple instructions in same cycle nor they can go out of order in the pipeline.

When you see a branch in the front end of the pipeline you have to make a decision about from where to fetch the next instruction, from branch target or from pc++. Branch resolution takes time, and if you wait, 3 or 20 cycles depending on the processor, you end up inserting that many bubbles. Branch prediction (BP) will help you start fetching from somewhere with some confidence.

The link between BP and Tomasulo's can be bridged by Reorder buffer, register files capable of handling misprediction recovery. There are many other things you need but this is a start. As soon as you know that the prediction you made was wrong, that is when you actually calculate the branch, you clear RoB and every possible buffer, pipeline stage, intermediate results affected by instructions on the speculated path up until the last committed instruction and then restart fetching from the correct PC.

Branch misprediction even on latest processor is costly and there are **tons** of optimizations to mitigate this and make BPs more accurate.

Hope this helps.